# Why php gettype function always returns string from a $_POST[$var]?

Tags: php, html, function

for example i have the following code

```
 <form action="viewer.php" method="post">
    <input type="number" name="roll" min="0" max="9999999" size="7" maxlength="7" required>
</form>
```

and the viewer.php file is

```
<?php
     $c=$_POST["roll"]; echo gettype($c);
?>
```

and it returns always string no matter whether i am submitting floats, ints or strngs -__-

and what should i do the get my expected ans?

thanks in advance

Comment: Because they *are* all strings when read from the POST payload (`foo=123&bar=-1` or multipart/ fields). Use [`is_numeric()`](http://php.net/is_numeric) or `ctype_*` functions to probe for type-equivalent content.

Comment: check using below code 

$c= (is_numeric($_POST['roll']) ? (int)$_POST['roll'] : 0);

Comment: gettype() Returns the type of the PHP variable var. For type checking, use is_* functions. you can get ref from http://www.hacksparrow.com/check-object-type-in-php.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want to test an object for a particular type
You know there are predefined object types in PHP, you just call the `is_*` functions to test. The following code shows you how to do the `is_*` testing.

- `is_null($var)` - true if $var is null
- `is_object($var)` - true if $var is an object
- `is_string($var)` - true if $var is a string
- `is_numeric($var)` - true if $var is a numeric string
- `is_int($var)` - true if $var is an integer
- `is_float($var)` - true if $var is floating point number
- `is_bool($var)` - true if $var is a boolean
- `is_array($var)` - true if $var is an array
- `is_resource($var)` - true if $var is a resource (mysql, file etc). Use
  get_resource_type to get the specific type.
- `is_scalar($var)` - true if $var is a scalar (primitive data types:
  int, float, string, boolean)
- `is_callable($var)` - true if $var is a function or works like a
  function